# How to request focus from VerticalGridSupportFragment item to RowsSupportFragment item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYmZU.png)

I have TV app which has section for movies. Layout contains 2 FrameLayout one for HorizontalGridView(genre) and second for VerticalGridView(movies). So when focus on movies first row item and I click to up button it does not request focus to genre. How can I fix this?